# Uncaught ReferenceError: Jsoup is not defined cordova

Tags: android, cordova, jsoup

I am trying to implement force update android application in Cordova , while iam trying to implement first of all I have to get my play store app version, so im put below code to get current play store app version, but it show some error, kindly give a solution to resolve this issue

code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>myapp</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app-media.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/material-design-iconic- 
 font.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/snackbar.min.css" 
 title="blue" media="screen" />

<script src="./js/snackbar.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- onload="onLoad();" -->
<body  class="color-green-bg">

<div class="overview-login">
    <div class="login-header">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
                    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#" 
 onclick="Exit();"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </nav>

        <div class="login_logo"><img src="images/C_logo_login.png" alt="C_logo"
                title="C_logo" /></div>
        <div class="login_CREW-Logo"><img src="images/C_logo.png" alt="C_logo" title="C_logo" />
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
 </body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="./Util/conts.js"></script>
<script src="./network_status.js"></script>

 <script  type="text/javascript" >

 $( document ).ready(function() {

//Here is the Code   
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 function onDeviceReady() {
          var newVersion = Jsoup.connect("myapp playstore url")
    .timeout(30000)
    .userAgent(
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get()
    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first()
    .ownText();
    alert(newVersion);

 };




 });



 </script>
 </html>
```

Error:

```
 jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Jsoup is not defined 
 ReferenceError: Jsoup is not defined
 at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> 
 (file:///android_asset/www/select_mindpool_media.html:78:26)
 at l (file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
 at c (file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined
 w.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: How are you importing jsoup into your cordova application?

Comment: I didn't import any jsoup I just past this code only if you know how to import jsoup kindly let me know,I'm new to this Cordova @JamesWong

Answer (score 0):

So far it doesn't look like jsoup is officially supported by Cordova/ PhoneGap. A quick look at the [official plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=jsoup) repository will return no result.

If you need to use jsoup, you will need to implement it into Cordova on your own. Read the [Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/).

But if all you want is to show a webpage, why don't you use a simple HTML `<iframe>` to embed it into the page you want?

Or better yet, just use the [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) which provides an in-app web browser view that displays any URL that is called.

Comment: there is no plugin available for jsoup, kindly let me know how to update my application where new application released in play store